# Google Chrome on iPad/iPhone doesn't open links after opening PDF in new tab

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, pdf, menu

I've got a website that is working fine on my desktop. When I check the website on my iPad Air or iPhone 5S (both iOS8) with Google Chrome I run into a problem. Safari works fine. On one page there are some links to PDF files that open in a new page using `target="_blank"`. This works fine.

After closing the tab with the PDF I return to the original website and the menu seems "frozen". I can still scroll and open other PDF files in new tabs but the navigation menu doesn't work anymore. I can't go to other pages and reloading the page doesn't help. If I click/touch a link in the menu it still receives the `click` because I added this code in my jQuery:

```
$("ul li a").click(function(){
    var hrefTest = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(hrefTest);
    alert("klik");
});
```

Both the alerts are shown and the `href` of the links is still fine. If I add `target="_blank"` to the menu links they open fine in a new tab. Obviously that's not what I want.

My menu is nothing fancy or strange but here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="desktopFirst"><a href="/movement/">Movement</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a class="active" href="/product/">Product</a></li>
    <li class="mobileFirst"><a href="/">Overview</a></li>
</ul>
```

How is it possible that the page still works but only my menu links don't go to their `href` links? As said above, this only happens on Google Chrome on iPad & iPhone. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

The website is currently running on [this website](http://www.carvingfitness.com). I can't figure out what's wrong, a bug or something with my code.

**EDIT 2**

I just found out after a lot of testing that the navigation doesn't work when the tab with the PDF is closed. If it is still open everything works fine. Anybody has any idea? I'm desperate here.

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue, I also noticed that I can't refresh the page, nor change the tab's URL or open the History tab. It's as if that tab is stuck on that URL and can not be changed.

**However**, if I close the tab and load it up again, open a PDF and close the PDF's tab everything works normally, navigation works 100%. If I then give the iPad a four-finger flick and swipe Chrome away from the task list, re-run it and navigate back to my page the issue is back again.

It's like when Chrome first loads and closes a PDF in a new tab something breaks on the parent tab, but only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, given you use `p` tags with `href` attributes, with the class name of `.link`:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    window.open(this.getAttribute("href"), "_blank");
});
```

This uses the same idea, but this time utilising the built-in `window.open()` function supplied by javascript. This simply opens the link of the button attribute, with the `_blank` parameter as the window name.

To style it, making it look like a link, use this in your stylesheet:

```
.link{
    color: blue;                 //Set the color to blue.
    font-family: sans;           //Set to default text, change if necessary.
    text-decoration: underline;  //Underline the link.
}
.link:hover{
    cursor: pointer;             //Make the cursor a pointer when hovering the link.
}
```

Some documentation of this method can be found here:

1. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
3. http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Comment: The `_blank` happens on the PDF link so that's just an `a` tag like `<a href="thelinktopdf" target="_blank">Text</a>`. If I put the code on that link the page goes to the PDF file and also opens a new tab with the PDF so I got two tabs with the PDF.

Comment: Try wrapping this in a iOS detector, by checking the user agent for an iOS string, so it only does that for iOS.

Comment: I wrapped it in an iOS detector but I end up with 2 tabs with the PDF and no website. If I close the second tab and try to do previous on the first tab it won't work so it's still "broken".

Comment: Try making your own link, using that script for all platforms, and just use an underlined 'p'  tag.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you explain the script? I just have 4 'a' tags that link to PDF files.

Comment: Just make the a tags p tags, and then give them the class 'link'. I will show you the rest

Comment: Just change the a tags to p tags, and set class="link".

Comment: They are p tags with class "pdf" and that has your code but it doesn't work.